# Knockout search without losing the structure of tree view

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a scenario where I need to filter the deepest child node, and I tried to use this code in my application, but it failed with nested tree items. Can you please help in handling nested items.

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.itemFilter = ko.observable("");

  self.items = ko.observableArray([{
      name: "name3", viewable: true,
      children: [{
        name: "name3-1", viewable: true,
        children: [
          {name: "name3-thordone", viewable: true},
          {name: "name3-thirdtwo", viewable: true},
        ]
      }]
    }
  ]);

  self.any = function(arr, condition) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (condition(arr[i]))
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  };

  self.matchText = function(source, query) {
    return source.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) !== -1;
  };

  self.filterItem = function(query, obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty('children')) {
      return self.matchText(obj.name, query) || self.any(obj.children, function(child) {
        return self.filterItem(query, child);
      });
    } else {
      return self.matchText(obj.name, query);
    }
  };

  self.filterArrayWithQuery = function(arr, query) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty('children')) {
        var matchingChildren = self.filterArrayWithQuery(obj.children, query);
        var subResult = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < matchingChildren.length; j++)
          subResult.push(matchingChildren[j]);
        if (subResult.length > 0)
          result.push(subResult);
      } else {
        if (self.matchText(obj.name, query))
          result.push(obj);
      }
    }
    return result;
  };

  self.nonNullItems = function(arr) {
    return arr.filter(function(x) {
      return x !== null;
    });
  };

  self.filteredObjectOrNull = function(obj, query) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty('children')) {
      console.log('obj.children');
      console.log(obj.children);
      var filteredChildren = self.nonNullItems(obj.children.filter(function(x) {
        console.log('x');
        console.log(x);

        return self.filteredObjectOrNull(x, query);
      }));
      console.log('filteredChildren')
      console.log(filteredChildren);
      if (filteredChildren.length > 0)
        return {
          name: obj.name,
          children: filteredChildren
        };
    }

    if (self.matchText(obj.name, query))
      return obj;

    return null;
  };

  self.filterItems = function() {
    var filter = self.itemFilter();

    if (filter === "") {
      return self.items();
    } else {
      return self.nonNullItems(self.items().map(function(x) {
        return self.filteredObjectOrNull(x, filter);
      }));
    }
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input data-bind="value: itemFilter, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" type="text" />
<p>Filter term: <span data-bind="text: itemFilter"></span></p>

<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'nav-list-template', foreach: filterItems(items()) }"></ul>

<script type="text/html" id="nav-list-template">
  <li>
    <a data-bind="text: name"></a>
    <!-- ko if: typeof children !== 'undefined' && children.length > 0 -->
    <ul>
      <!-- ko template: { name: 'nav-list-template', foreach: children } -->
      <!--/ko -->
    </ul>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </li>
</script>
```

jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fevctxdj/

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking too complicated, all those helper functions are not even needed.

A tree consists of nodes, so let's make a viewmodel for nodes. It needs to contain

- the `name` and any other initial properties
- an (observable) array of `children`
- an observable `isVisible` that can be true or false. It's true by default.
- a computed value `hasVisibleChildren` for later convenience (a simple search over the `children`)

Tree nodes can build themselves recursively, so the entire tree constructs itself from your nested input.

And we need a container viewmodel that holds the `root` node and the `itemFilter`.

And *then* all we need is a recursive function that sets `isVisible` on every node based on name match, or child visibility. We can subscribe to the `itemFilter` to run as soon as the user types anything:

```js
function TreeNode(params) {
  this.name = ko.observable(params.name);
  this.viewable = ko.observable(params.viewable);
  this.children = ko.observableArray((params.children || []).map(child => new TreeNode(child)));
  this.isVisible = ko.observable(true);
  this.hasVisibleChildren = ko.pureComputed(() => this.children().some(child => child.isVisible()));
}

function FilterTree(params) {
  var self = this;

  self.itemFilter = ko.observable("");
  self.root = new TreeNode({children: params.items});

  self.itemFilter.subscribe(function (searchValue) {
    searchValue = searchValue.toLowerCase().trim();
    self.root.children().forEach(function setVisible(child) {
      child.children().forEach(setVisible);   // descend into the tree first...
      child.isVisible(                        // and then we can decide child visibility
        child.name().toLowerCase().includes(searchValue) || child.hasVisibleChildren()
      );
    });
  });
}

var vm = new FilterTree({
  items: [{
    name: "name3", viewable: true, children: [{
      name: "name3-1", viewable: true, children: [
        {name: "name3-thordone", viewable: true},
        {name: "name3-thirdtwo", viewable: true},
      ]
    }]
  }]
});
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input data-bind="textInput: itemFilter" type="text" />
<p>Filter term: <span data-bind="text: itemFilter"></span></p>

<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'nav-list-template', foreach: root.children }"></ul>

<script type="text/html" id="nav-list-template">
  <li data-bind="visible: isVisible">
    <a data-bind="text: name"></a>
    <ul data-bind="visible: hasVisibleChildren, template: {name: 'nav-list-template', foreach: children}"></ul>
  </li>
</script>
```

Notes:

- You're using the `if` binding. The `if` binding dynamically re-builds its content (i.e. "throws it away when the condition becomes false"), which is inefficient for larger trees. Switching to the `visible` binding builds the DOM once, and then Knockout only toggles elements via CSS. This will perform a lot better.
- Another way to reduce the number of wasted calculations is to [rate-limit](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/rateLimit-observable.html) the `itemFilter`, i.e. to change the behavior from "recalculate for every keystroke" to "recalculate when the user has stopped typing":

  ```
  self.itemFilter = ko.observable("").extend({rateLimit: {timeout: 300, method: "notifyWhenChangesStop"}});
  ```
- As a stress test, I've constructed my own test data (25,000 nodes, 5,000 inner nodes, 20,000 leaf nodes, maximum depth of 18). On my (2016 Core i5 6300U) machine, the above takes Firefox about 200-300 ms to build that sample tree, `ko.applyBindings()` takes maybe 5 seconds sort it all out. So the initialization takes a while, but that's *a lot* of nodes, arguably more than would be reasonable all at once in any web application. After rendering, searching is pretty snappy.

Comment: I tried to use this in my code . However i get (params.children || []).map is not a function

Comment: @user2940334 The above is working when `.children` is either undefined, or an array. Check your data.

Comment: I fixed the issue with data . can you please suggest a  way to handle this without computed observable ?

Comment: this approach seems to work , however I face UI freezing issue when it has huge number of children . Not sure how to handle it

Comment: @learner Sorry, I must have missed your reply. But what do you mean by *"without computed observable"*? Do you want to use knockout, or not? If you want to use knockout, computed observables are not optional.

Comment: Also, how many tree items are we talking about? You could replace the `if` binding (which re-renders the tree) with a [`visible` binding](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html), which only sets visibility via CSS. This should be faster.

Comment: @learner I've added that to the answer, try it out.

Comment: I already have ratelimit added to my observable . Each node can have 10-12 child nodes and those nodes are different view models . I will try changing the if property and see how it works

Comment: @learner If this still is slow, and you have some sample data to share, I could also try my hand on optimizing this further.

Comment: @learner FWIW I've constructed my own test data (25,000 nodes, 5,000 inner nodes, 20,000 leaf nodes, maximum depth of 18). On my (2016 Core i5 6300U) machine, the above takes Firefox about 200-300 ms to build that sample tree, `ko.applyBindings()` takes maybe 5 seconds sort it all out. So the initialization takes a while, but that's *a lot* of nodes, arguably more than would be reasonable all at once in any web application. But after rendering, searching is pretty snappy.

Comment: I could think of some more optimizations, like caching the lower-case node names, but that's quickly getting into "diminishing returns" territory. This might already be good enough. Also note that I've streamlined my answer and made a few changes to the code.

Comment: Thank you and let me try and see . But did you do any changes to the code

Comment: @learner Minor changes. You can show the diff when you click at the "edited" link below the answer

Comment: Another optimization would be to get rid of any observables in `TreeNode` that will not change their values over the life-time of the page, i.e. `name` and `children`. They could be a plain string and a plain array, respectively. Doing that would remove a bunch of function calls when searching, and probably shave off a few ms.

Comment: @learner Any feedback?

Comment: I did not have a chance to work on this . I might work on it back next week and I will update you . Thanks

Comment: I tried this , since my dataset has 12000 points UI is crashing . Hence going to abandon this approach

Comment: @learner you shoud think *really hard* if letting the client handle this much data all at once is a good UI strategy. The above works fairly well for way beyond reasonable amounts of data. Think of a better approach. Loading all you data onto the client indiscriminately is not it.